# C# webkit.net enable popup

Tags: c#, .net, popup, window.open, webkit.net

In a C# webkit.net browser how to enable a popup window created by JavaScript window.open()?

I tried these properties:

```
this.webKitBrowser1.IsScriptingEnabled = true;
this.webKitBrowser1.AllowNewWindows = true;
```

But nothing changed. I also tried this event:

```
this.webKitBrowser1.NewWindowCreated += new WebKit.NewWindowCreatedEventHandler(webKitBrowser1_NewWindowCreated);
```

But it isn't fire up.

Comment: any update on this question..I am facing the same problem now?

Comment: martin- did you solve this issue?